# How to get a list from JSON record in MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I would like to get a list that is a field in a JSON file, which is a record in a mysql table. I am using the following query:

```py
cursor = self.database.cursor()
sql = """ SELECT result->>"$.my_list" FROM my_table
          WHERE my_id = 5 ORDER BY date ASC """
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Using '->' the result is in the string format: '[a,b,c,d], [a,b,c,d]' or using '->>' the result is binary: b'[a,b,c,d]', b'[a,b,c,d]'.

How can I convert it (or get directly) a normal python list object?

Comment: `resultJson = json.loads(result)` might work with the string format.

Comment: It could be a solution, but Is it possible without loading the whole JSON object?

Comment: scotty3785 It works for the lists as well ;) Thanks!